# add a numeric index in mysql table

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table with 6 columns having two columns jointly acting as a primary key.

However, I now want to add a numeric index column for each row in the table, so that I can fetch a specific number of rows at a time and keep track to fetch new data every time.

Sorting the current columns would take a lot of time each time as the table is huge.

What can be the best solution?

Comment: This just sounds like a bad idea

Comment: why? @Strawberry

Comment: Because rows get deleted, and because ORDER BY and LIMIT are just fine for this purpose.

Comment: "Sorting takes a lot of time" -- What sort order do you need?

Comment: Related tips can be found [_here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig).

Answer (score -1):

add a new column with auto increment int values and make it primary key:

```
alter table myTable add new_primary_id int primary key auto_increment first
```

Comment: The new id does not need to be `PRIMARY KEY`, it can be just `INDEX`.

Comment: @Strawberry - Being the first in _any_ index is sufficient for an auto_inc.  [_Reference_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) .  (Plus, I have done it on several tables.)

Comment: @Strawberry - quoting from that page:  "To use the AUTO_INCREMENT mechanism with an InnoDB table, an AUTO_INCREMENT column must be defined as part of an index such that it is possible to perform the equivalent of an indexed SELECT MAX(ai_col) lookup on the table to obtain the maximum column value. Typically, this is achieved by making the column the first column of some table index."

Comment: I am suggesting that the OP need not lose his current PK, but rather add `id AUTO_INCREMENT, INDEX(id)`.  And resolving the as-yet-unremarked-upon issue that Nasif causes:  a table cannot have 2 PKs.

Comment: @RickJames Ah, I think I see - I hadn't realised that it could be used with (for instance) a unique key instead. (Or just KEY) - how did I not know that??

Comment: @Strawberry - One User has many Photos.  To cluster all photos together for a user in the Photos table:  `PRIMARY KEY(userid, photoid), INDEX(photoid)` -- note that photoid is `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  This can significantly improve performance over the obvious.

Comment: @RickJames 'The obvious'? You mean `PRIMARY KEY(photo_id), UNIQUE(userid,photoid)`

Comment: @Strawberry - Absolutely not -- The data is clustered based on PK, so I want the PK to start with userid.  Adding the photo_id makes the PK UNIQUE.  Then INDEX(photo_id) keeps AUTO_INCREMENT minimally happy.

Comment: @Strawberry - The one thing missing is that you _could_ `INSERT` a duplicate `photo_id` with being caught.  But you wouldn't.  So, saying `UNIQUE(photo_id)` is a waste (and it would slow down `INSERTs` to check for the dup that you won't do).

Comment: A PK is `UNIQUE`; when I see another `UNIQUE`, I look more closely.  I find that having two unique keys is _rarely_ the 'right' thing to do.

Comment: @Strawberry - I was using MySQL for several years before I discovered this little performance kludge.